# I can't create issues by email on Redmine 4.0.2

Tags: redmine

I can't create issues by email on Redmine 4.0.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.

I've deployed Redmine, created a project, users, roles, trackers, and defaults categories, priorities and activities. I can create issues manually, but I can't create them by sending a mail to a mailbox.

This is the command that I'm running unsucessfully, no Issue is created:

```
# sudo -u www-data rake -f /opt/redmine/Rakefile redmine:email:receive_imap \
                         RAILS_ENV=production \
                         host=imap.gmail.com \
                         port=993 \
                         ssl=1 \
                         username=myuser@mydomain.com \
                         password=mypassword \
                         project=MyProject \
                         unknown_user=accept \
                         no_permission_check=1  \
                         allow_override=tracker,priority,project,status,category \
                         --trace
** Invoke redmine:email:receive_imap (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute redmine:email:receive_imap
```

I also tried it specifying all the parameters, as shown in *lib/tasks/email.rake* , with same results :

```
# sudo -u www-data rake -f /opt/redmine/Rakefile redmine:email:receive_imap \
                         RAILS_ENV=production \
                         host=imap.gmail.com \
                         port=993 \
                         ssl=1 \
                         username=myuser@mydomain.com \
                         password=mypassword \
                         project=MyProject \
                         unknown_user=accept \
                         no_permission_check=1 \
                         tracker=Issue \
                         priority=Normal \
                         status=Open \
                         category=unassigned \
                         --trace
```

And this is what appears in the log file **/opt/redmine/log/production.log** :

```
Creating scope :system. Overwriting existing method Enumeration.system.
```

The IMAP connection is right, because if I alter the credentials then the execution fails.

Any help would be much appreciated. Best regards,

Edit: Here are the contents of the ***ENV*** hash that's passed to *MailHandler.extract_options_from_env* in the line 121 of Redmine's *lib/tasks/email.rake* : https://gist.github.com/zoquero/7d7cacca51ac25d939aeb13a7030fb27

Answer (score 1):

The call to `redmine:email:receive_imap` **is correct**. By another reason (bad configuration of mine) the new mails were set as *read* before calling it. As can be seen in `Redmine::IMAP.check`, in the file `redmine/lib/redmine/imap.rb` , **it just looks for mails marked as `NOT SEEN`**. It should have seemed obvious to me, sorry.

Anyway I hope it helps somebody trying to create Issues in Redmine by incomming mails.

Best regards,

/Ángel